# CSS/HTML: Setting a table/div to max height of visible area, DID set parent elements

Tags: css

Here's my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ardashev120101/aweff/30/

```
html,body
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   border: none;
}
```

even with the HTML, Body heights set to 100%, and my "container" class to 90%, it is still occupying more than the available screen real estate!

The images are supposed to be dynamically adjusting their widths.... is that the problem?

The table is instead merely extending off the bottom of the screen. :'(

http://jsfiddle.net/Ardashev120101/aweff/30/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Tables always use `width` and `height` properties as rough guidelines. If the content doesn't fit, then showing all the content has a higher priority than obeying the CSS rules!

Solution: make the images smaller. Or, if all you're doing is show a list of images, use a list rather than a table.

By the way, those alt texts are by far the worst alt texts I've ever seen.

Comment: The images within should be scaling though...no?

Comment: --> CSS sets max height, 
--> table sets 100%, obtains a "width" from that
--> tr, td adjust
--> images adjust to said td, tr

Comment: Then I don't understand what the problem is, apparently. I thought the problem was that the table height is larger than 90% of the window? The width is just 100%, there's nothing wrong about that.

Comment: mhm! the height is the problem, I'm saying the images' widths adjust according to height

Comment: No! You can't adjust a width "according to height"! The image widths are simply 100% of the available width. And since the table width isn't set, the available width is the width of the body. Test this by setting the width of the table, say to 50%. Then you will see that the images are half as wide as the body as well. And the table still will treat the 90% height as a minimum height.